# Slow Google Maps Response Normal?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I was wondering whether anyone experienced the same slow responsiveness of Google Maps while working with:

`func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool`.

It takes more than 1 second to get a response from tapping markers. Is there any way to make it quicker?

Thank you!